# Retrieve Single IP Address from WMI Query in C#.NET

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm using a WMI query in C#.NET to retrieve the IP addresses on enabled adapters using the code below;

```
ManagementObjectSearcher NetworkSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT IPAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = 'TRUE'");

foreach (ManagementObject NetworkObj in NetworkSearcher.Get())
{
     String[] arrIPAddress = (String[])(NetworkObj["IPAddress"]);

     MessageBox.Show(arrIPAddress[0]);
     //sIPAddress = arrIPAddress[0];
}
```

If I message box out location 0 of the arrIPAddress array, I get two separate message boxes, one after the other, the first contains the IPv4 address of the first NIC, the second is the IPv6 address of the first NIC also. (If I try referencing 1 in the array I get the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses separately for the second NIC)

What I want to achieve is to then assign only the first IPv4 address (displayed in the very first message box) to the variable 'sIPAddress' but I can't workout how to separate the array properly. I tried seeing if there was a second element to the array (such as arrIPAddres[0,1] but there is no such second property.)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was kindly answered for me in another forum (link [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6198f289-aa2c-4eb5-a684-65b3d4ae2f79/retrieve-single-ip-address-from-wmi-query-in-visual-c?forum=csharpgeneral#6198f289-aa2c-4eb5-a684-65b3d4ae2f79))

But the code that ultimately provided what I wanted was as follows;

```
foreach( ManagementObject NetworkObj in NetworkSearcher.Get() )
{
string[] arrIPAddress = (string[])( NetworkObj["IPAddress"] );

sIPAddress = arrIPAddress.FirstOrDefault( s => s.Contains( '.' ) );

if( sIPAddress != null ) break;
}
```